# Photoshop: How to save EXR from script?

Tags: photoshop-scripting

Photoshop2020 seems to have EXR support. I can't find in the scripting reference of PS2019 any mention though of how to save EXR files and I also couldn't find a scripting reference for the 2020 version of Photoshop.

Does someone know where to find the 2020 scripting reference or how to save EXR from script?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ScriptingListener code to save an EXR:

```
saveEXR('/D/temp/mydfile.exr');

/**
 * @description saves EXR using Photoshop EXR Export
 * @param  {string} path    - a full path of exr to save as a string, ex /c/temp/myfile.exr
 * @param  {object} options - if you want to add any options
 *
 * @return nothing
 */
function saveEXR(path, options)
{
  var desc5 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var desc6 = new ActionDescriptor();
  desc6.putInteger(charIDToTypeID('BtDp'), 16);
  desc6.putInteger(charIDToTypeID('Cmpr'), 0);
  desc6.putInteger(charIDToTypeID('AChn'), 0);
  desc5.putObject(charIDToTypeID('As  '), charIDToTypeID('EXRf'), desc6);
  desc5.putPath(charIDToTypeID('In  '), new File(path));
  executeAction(charIDToTypeID('save'), desc5, DialogModes.NO);
} // end of saveEXR()
```

However Photoshop support for EXR is very basic and you might want to use something like [EXR-IO](https://www.exr-io.com/). Here's its export wrapped to a function:

```
saveEXRIO('/D/Temp/whatevs.exr');

/**
 * @description saves EXR using EXR-IO plugin
 * @param  {string} path    - a full path of exr to save as a string, ex /c/temp/myfile.exr
 * @param  {object} options - here you'll probably want to modify the options
 *
 * @return nothing
 */
function saveEXRIO(path, options) {
    var desc14 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var desc15 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc15.putBoolean(charIDToTypeID('iolc'), false);
    desc15.putBoolean(charIDToTypeID('iowt'), false);
    desc15.putBoolean(charIDToTypeID('iohl'), false);
    desc15.putBoolean(charIDToTypeID('iosl'), true);
    desc15.putBoolean(charIDToTypeID('iosw'), true);
    desc15.putInteger(charIDToTypeID('iocs'), 2);
    desc15.putInteger(charIDToTypeID('iotw'), 128);
    desc15.putInteger(charIDToTypeID('ioth'), 128);
    desc15.putDouble(charIDToTypeID('iocl'), 45.000000);
    desc15.putString(charIDToTypeID('iodt'), "LOAT");
    desc15.putString(charIDToTypeID('ioct'), "ip");
    desc15.putString(charIDToTypeID('iotl'), "ingle");
    desc14.putObject(charIDToTypeID('As  '), stringIDToTypeID('3d-io Exr-IO'), desc15);
    desc14.putPath(charIDToTypeID('In  '), new File(path));
    executeAction(charIDToTypeID('save'), desc14, DialogModes.NO);
} // end of saveEXRIO()
```

To learn what options do what you can experiment with [Scripting Listener](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html#ScriptingListenerplugin).

---